# Django inlineformset: PK missing in subform -> form_set.is_valid() = False

Tags: django

I have followed this [tutorial](https://swapps.com/blog/working-with-nested-forms-with-django/) to implement inlneformset.

CreateView works (data is registered in database) but UpdateView doesn't.

UpdateView is correctly displayed with correct data.

But it seems like subform (application inlineformset) is never valid and I don't understand why?

forms.py:

```
NAME = Thesaurus.options_list(2,'fr')
ACCESS = Thesaurus.options_list(3,'fr') 
ApplicationFormset = inlineformset_factory(
    Utilisateur, Application, 
    fields=('app_app_nom','app_dro'),
    widgets={
        'app_app_nom': forms.Select(choices=NAME),
        'app_dro': forms.Select(choices=ACCESS)
    },
    extra=3,
    can_delete=True,
)
```

models.py:

```
class Projet(SafeDeleteModel):

    _safedelete_policy = SOFT_DELETE_CASCADE
    pro_ide = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
    pro_nom = models.IntegerField("Nom du projet", null=True, blank=True)
    pro_log = models.CharField("Log utiisateur", max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    pro_dat = models.DateTimeField("Date log",auto_now_add=True)
    pro_act = models.IntegerField("Projet en cours ?", null=True, blank=True)
    log = HistoricalRecords()

    class Meta:

        db_table = 'tbl_pro'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Projets'
        ordering = ['pro_ide']
        permissions = [
            ('can_add_project','Can add project'),
        ]

class Utilisateur(SafeDeleteModel):

    _safedelete_policy = SOFT_DELETE_CASCADE
    uti_ide = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
    pro_ide = models.ForeignKey(Projet, on_delete = models.CASCADE) # related project
    uti_nom = models.CharField("Nom", max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    uti_pre = models.CharField("Prénom", max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    uti_mai = models.CharField("Email", max_length=40, null=True, blank=True)
    uti_sit = models.CharField("Equipe", max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    uti_pro = models.CharField("Fonction/profil", max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    uti_dem_dat = models.DateTimeField("Date demande",auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)
    uti_val = models.IntegerField("Demande validée ?", null=True, blank=True)
    uti_val_dat = models.DateTimeField("Date validation",auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)
    uti_log = models.CharField("Log utilisateur", max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    uti_dat = models.DateTimeField("Date log",auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)
    log = HistoricalRecords()

    @classmethod
    def options_list(cls,pro_ide):

        projet = Projet.objects.get(pro_ide=pro_ide)
        utilisateurs = Utilisateur.objects.filter(pro_ide=projet.pro_ide)
        the_opts_list = [(utilisateur.uti_ide, utilisateur.uti_nom+', '+utilisateur.uti_pre) for utilisateur in utilisateurs]
        the_opts_list.insert(0, (None, ''))
        return the_opts_list

    class Meta:

        db_table = 'tbl_uti'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Utilisateurs'
        ordering = ['uti_ide']


class Application(SafeDeleteModel):

    _safedelete_policy = SOFT_DELETE_CASCADE
    app_ide = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
    uti_ide = models.ForeignKey(Utilisateur, on_delete = models.CASCADE) # related utilisateur
    app_app_nom = models.IntegerField("Nom application", null=True, blank=True)
    app_dro = models.IntegerField("Droit sur application", null=True, blank=True)
    app_sta = models.IntegerField("Statut (création/Modification/Suppression", null=True, blank=True)
    app_log = models.CharField("Log utilisateur", max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    app_dat = models.DateTimeField("Date log",auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)
    log = HistoricalRecords()

    class Meta:

        db_table = 'tbl_app'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Applications'
        ordering = ['app_ide']


class Administration(SafeDeleteModel):

    _safedelete_policy = SOFT_DELETE_CASCADE
    adm_ide = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
    app_ide = models.ForeignKey(Application, on_delete = models.CASCADE) # related application
    adm_nom = models.CharField("Nom d'utilisateur dans l'application", max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    adm_dem = models.IntegerField("Demande traitée ?", null=True, blank=True)
    adm_dem_dat = models.DateTimeField("Date traitement de la demande",auto_now_add=True)
    adm_log = models.CharField("Log utilisateur", max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    adm_dat = models.DateTimeField("Date log",auto_now_add=True)
    log = HistoricalRecords()

    class Meta:

        db_table = 'tbl_adm'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Adminitrations'
        ordering = ['adm_ide']
        permissions = [
            ('can_manage_project','Can manage project'),
        ]
```

UpdateView:

```
class UtilisateurUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Utilisateur
    fields = ['uti_nom','uti_pre','uti_mai','uti_sit','uti_pro']

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
            data["utilisateur"] = self.request.user.username
            data["application"] = ApplicationFormset(self.request.POST, instance=self.object)
        else:
            data["application"] = ApplicationFormset(instance=self.object)
        return data

    def form_valid(self, form):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        application = context["application"]
        self.object = form.save()
        self.object.save()

        if application.is_valid(): # ***** NEVER VALID *****
            application.instance = self.object
            print('application.instance',application.instance)
            application.app_app_nom = application.instance.cleaned_data['app_app_nom']
            application.app_dro = application.instance.cleaned_data['app_dro']
            application.app_log = context["utilisateur"]
            application.uti_ide = 1
            application.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse("project:index")
```

Comment: in fact, form is not valid and I have this: errors [{'app_ide': ['This field is required.']}, {}, {}, {}] ; app_ide is the PK of Application models used for inlineformset...

Answer (score 0):

I have resolve my problem: I forget to insert form_set id in my html template (app_ide in my case)